# Are there forbidden characters for elasticsearch aliasing?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to [fake index per user](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/faking-it.html) but my user id's are emails. When I have a `@` in my aliases, searches are empty.

For example, if I create one index `my_index` and two aliases `my_alias` and `my@lias` as below, my_alias search is working fine and my@lias is not :

```
curl -XPUT 'elasticsearch:9200/my_index'
{"acknowledged":true}

curl -XPUT 'elasticsearch:9200/my_index/_alias/my_alias -d '{"routing": "my_alias", "filter": {"term": {"doc_id": "my_alias"}}}'
{"acknowledged":true}

curl -XPUT 'elasticsearch:9200/my_index/_alias/my@lias' -d '{"routing": "my@lias", "filter": {"term": {"doc_id": "my@lias"}}}'
{"acknowledged":true}

curl -XPUT 'elasticsearch:9200/my_alias/doc/1' -d '{doc_id:"my_alias", title: "hello world"}'
{"_index":"my_index","_type":"doc","_id":"1","_version":1,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"created":true}

curl -XPUT 'elasticsearch:9200/my@lias/doc/2' -d '{doc_id:"my@lias", title: "hello dude"}'
{"_index":"my_index","_type":"doc","_id":"2","_version":1,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"created":true}

curl -XGET 'elasticsearch:9200/my_alias/doc/_search?pretty=true' -d'{"query": {"match": {"title": "hello"}}}'
{
    "took" : 1,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 1,
        "successful" : 1,
        "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
        "total" : 1,
        "max_score" : 0.19178301,
        "hits" : [ {
            "_index" : "my_index",
            "_type" : "doc",
            "_id" : "1",
            "_score" : 0.19178301,
            "_routing" : "my_alias",
            "_source" : {
                "doc_id" : "my_alias",
                "title" : "hello world"
            }
        } ]
    }
}

curl -XGET 'elasticsearch:9200/my@lias/doc/_search?pretty=true' -d'{"query": {"match": {"title": "hello"}}}'
{
    "took" : 1,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 1,
        "successful" : 1,
        "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
        "total" : 0,
        "max_score" : null,
        "hits" : [ ]
    }
}
```

What puzzles me is that there is no `Invalid Alias Name Exception`, and the search result is ok, but empty.

I tried also with url-encoding `%40` : `elasticsearch:9200/my%40lias` but it is the same.

If I search on the whole index, I see the two documents. If I create an index with `@`, the index searches are ok also. If I curl the _aliases to see the ES status I can see it :

```
"my_index" : {
  "aliases" : {
    "my@lias" : {
      "filter" : {
        "term" : {
          "doc_id" : "my@lias"
        }
      },
      "index_routing" : "my@lias",
      "search_routing" : "my@lias"
    },
    "my_alias" : {
      "filter" : {
        "term" : {
          "doc_id" : "my_alias"
        }
      },
      "index_routing" : "my_alias",
      "search_routing" : "my_alias"
    }
  }
},
```

Do you see any reason for that behavior ? Do I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to URL-encode the `@` sign like this:

```
curl -XGET 'elasticsearch:9200/my%40lias/doc/_search?pretty=true'
                                  ^
                                  |
                             change this
```

Comment: oups I should have mentioned that I tried this, but it is not a problem of url encoding either, I'm editing the post

Comment: Hmm, it might have to do with the way you're using routing.

Comment: well  maybe, but it is exactly the same than the link above, and it is working with one and not with the other...

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your index in my local and I think that the problem you have is that you're not indexing the documents correctly.

For example , take a look at this request :

```
curl -XPUT 'elasticsearch:9200/my_alias/doc/1' -d '{doc_id:"my_alias", title: "hello world"}'
```

It should be

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_alias/doc/1" -d'
{"doc_id":"my_alias", "title": "hello world"}'
```

Please note the difference between  **{doc_id:"my_alias"** and **{"doc_id":"my_alias",** as your are missing the quotation marks for the doc_id . This applies for the title as well.

Full fixed example :

```
PUT /my_index
PUT /my_index/_alias/my_alias
{"routing": "my_alias", "filter": {"term": {"doc_id": "my_alias"}}}

PUT /my_index/_alias/my@lias
{"routing": "my@lias", "filter": {"term": {"doc_id": "my@lias"}}}

PUT /my_alias/doc/1
{
  "doc_id":"my_alias", "title": "hello world"

}

PUT /my@lias/doc/2
{
  "doc_id": "my@lias",
  "title": "hello dude"
}


GET /my_alias/doc/_search?pretty=true
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "hello"
    }
  }
}

{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.19178301,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.19178301,
        "_routing": "my_alias",
        "_source": {
          "doc_id": "my_alias",
          "title": "hello world"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: not fixed at all, read the question please : there are two cases, one with my_alias, that is passing, and another with my@lias that is not. How would you explain that the first example is working based on the fact that I would have forgotten the double quotes ??